# Changing error message for System.Exception() in C#

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I am just starting to learn about error handling and exceptions in C# and I'm trying to find a way set a specific error message if I use `throw new System.Exception()`.

So for example I have a class where I define a custom data type `Vector` and one of the methods I include is a way to `Set` and `Get` the values in the `Vector` (which is really just 1D array) based on the index.
And if for some reason an invalid index is passed (eg. index < 1 or greater than the size of the vector) I would like to throw an exception.

eg.

```
Vector v = new Vector(3); //initialize a vector with 3 components
v[4] = 1; //try to store value in memory outside the range of the vector
```

In the Vector class code I try something like:

```
try
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= vector.length)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Invalid index used to set vector component value"); //throw exception with new message
    }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Writeline("Message: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

In my mind this would display the new message in the console "**Invalid index used to set vector component value**" but instead it just displays the message associated with the `IndexOutOfRangeException()` "**Index was outside the bounds of the array**".

Could someone please explain what would be the correct way to do this? I know I could just use the `IndexOutOfRangeException()` and leave it at that but I would really like to be able to write my own error messages so they make troubleshooting easier. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

It's been pointed out that my `if` conditions for throwing the exception were the problem, I set the second condition to be `>` when it should be `>=`. I've fixed it and now it works as expected.

Comment: Can you share your entire method?

Comment: The code posted doesn't show the behavior you told us. It throws correctly the message in the System.Exception constructor. So something else happens here that you haven't show us. On a different line of thought you shouldn't use the System.Exception for your own purposes. Just build a new class derived from System.Exception and add any functionality needed there

Comment: Your index check has on off-by-one error. There are `length + 1` values ranging, inclusively, from `0` to `length`. But there are only `length` valid indexes. Should be `>=` rather than `>` for the second comparison.

Comment: as a best practice, try create a new derived class from Exception class as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions)

Comment: But that code that triggers the exception (_v[4] = 1_) is inside the try/catch block?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Steve You are both right and this is what was causing the issue. It was catching the default exception because the trigger for my one wasn't, well, triggering. Apologies, I really should have noticed that myself.

Comment: @Steve thank you I didn't know that was an option, I see that would be a much better way than throwing `System.Exception()` x amount of times around the code.

Answer (score 0):

Then don't `catch` the generic exception first .. rather catch the specific one first and then the generic exception

```
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    Console.Writeline($"Message: {e.Message + "\t" + "Invalid index used to set vector component value"}");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Writeline("Message: {0}", e.Message);
}
```